# Getting started with serial port (COM port)

Tags: linux, parallel-port, com-port

I'm beginner in hardware building and curious about using my parallel port. Could someone suggest me how to start work with it? What cables I have to buy? How get simple I/O using COM port? How program it on my GNU/Linux operating system?

Comment: The parallel port is also called the LPT port. The COM port is a serial RS-232 port. They are two different ports and types of I/O.  Why are you asking about both as if they were one and the same?

Comment: I'm new in this, can have misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked these fairly detailed documents

http://as6edriver.sourceforge.net/Parallel-Port-Programming-HOWTO/parallel-port-programming-howto.html

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO.html

Comment: Thanks, is there suggestions hot to start build hardware? How I can connect my random device to that ports?

Comment: Not sure about actual hardware as I am more of a software person. That said I'd suggest taking a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux might get you rolling without having to bother with actual hardware right to start with.